# Use $e^{ia}+e^{ib}$ to show that $y(t)=2A\cos(\frac{\delta}{2}t-\frac{\phi_1 -\phi_2}{2})\sin((\omega+\frac{\delta}{2})t+\frac{\phi_1 +\phi_2}{2})$

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers, harmonic-functions

One guitarist causes an oscillation given by
$$y_1(t)=A\sin({\omega}t+\phi_1)$$

Another guitarist causes an oscillation given by
$$y_2(t)=A\sin({(\omega+\delta)}t+\phi_2)$$

Furthermore, 
$$y(t)=y_1(t)+y_2(t)$$

Given formula (1)
$$e^{ia}+e^{ib}=2e^{i\frac{(a+b)}{2}}\cos(\frac{a-b}{2})$$

Formula (1) should be used to show
$$y(t)=2A\cos(\frac{\delta}{2}t-\frac{\phi_1 -\phi_2}{2})\sin((\omega+\frac{\delta}{2})t+\frac{\phi_1 +\phi_2}{2})$$
I've attempted adding $y_1(t)$ and $y_2(t)$, hoping that something useful would drop out. However, this becomes quite messy after using angle sum identities and I can't make sense of it. I've considered double angle formulae, product-to-sum, sum-to-product formulae. What is a good approach to solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't use your equation (1), but by the Prosthaphaeresis Formulas (see http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\begin{aligned}&\sin(\omega t + \phi_1)+\sin((\omega+\delta)t+\phi_2) = \\
&=2\sin\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega t + \phi_1 + (\omega+\delta)t+\phi_2\right)\right)\cos\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\omega t + \phi_1 - (\omega+\delta)t-\phi_2\right)\right)\\
&=2\sin\left((\omega+\frac{\delta}{2})t+\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2}\right)\cos\left(-\frac{\delta}{2}t+\frac{\phi_1-\phi_2}{2}\right)\\
&=2\sin\left((\omega+\frac{\delta}{2})t+\frac{\phi_1+\phi_2}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{\delta}{2}t-\frac{\phi_1-\phi_2}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}$$